# Regex for Url Rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this Rewrite

```
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?q=([^&\ ]+)
#RewriteRule ^ /q/%1? [L,NE,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^q/(.*)$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

It's work fine.. for `www.mysite.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=`

But now i changed my search method
my url is

`www.mysite.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=`

How I can change my rewrite? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want `?cat=meow&q=query` to be written to? mayb `/q/meow/cat/meow` ?

Comment: yes! please.. it's ok

Comment: I think my comment should say `/q/query/cat/meow`

Comment: yes.. really  /q/query/cat/meow is right

Answer (score 0):

Played around with it some more thanks to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be and came up with that you could just use the `QUERY_STRING` as the rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /q/%1? [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^q/(.*)$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

Results:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)  This condition was met
RewriteRule ^ /q/%1? [L,NE,R=301]   This rule was met, the new url is:
                                    http://www.example.com/q/something&cat=123
```

Comment: No.. nothing.. i'm trying to do something on regex101

Comment: If i use catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=blablabla it's work (in cat no value)
if i use catalogsearch/result?cat=123&q=blalbalba it doesn't work

Comment: OK see update... Keep in mind, that it's not going to capture anything from `q` unless `q` is at least one character.

Comment: nothing to do... with every 2 i have Internal Server Error